# How does this function compare hexnumbers?

Tags: hash, md5

```
var int a0 := 0x67452301   //A
var int b0 := 0xefcdab89   //B
var int c0 := 0x98badcfe   //C
var int d0 := 0x10325476   //D    

for each 512-bit chunk of message
        break chunk into sixteen 32-bit words M[j], 0 ≤ j ≤ 15
    //Initialize hash value for this chunk:
        var int A := a0
        var int B := b0
        var int C := c0
        var int D := d0
    //Main loop:
        for i from 0 to 63
            if 0 ≤ i ≤ 15 then
                F := (B and C) or ((not B) and D)
                g := i
            else if 16 ≤ i ≤ 31
                F := (D and B) or ((not D) and C)
                g := (5×i + 1) mod 16
            else if 32 ≤ i ≤ 47
                F := B xor C xor D
                g := (3×i + 5) mod 16
            else if 48 ≤ i ≤ 63
                F := C xor (B or (not D))
                g := (7×i) mod 16
            dTemp := D
            D := C
            C := B
            B := B + leftrotate((A + F + K[i] + M[g]), s[i])
            A := dTemp
        end for
    //Add this chunk's hash to result so far:
        a0 := a0 + A
        b0 := b0 + B
        c0 := c0 + C
        d0 := d0 + D
    end for
```

This is taken from wikipedia, specifically from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5), to see the full code.

I fail to understand what for example `(B and C)` produces, as `B` and `C` are hexes. (Big endian)

Comment: I do not see a security related question here. Perhaps you can rephrase the question you have if it is related to security.

Comment: These hexnumbers are just regular numbers, written for the programmer's eyes in hexademical notation. It's all 1s and 0s under the hood. The and, or, not, and xor are [bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bitwise_operators).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`B and C` is the bitwise (32bit) boolean AND operation. So for example the int 15 (0xf) and 17 (0x11) result in 1 (0x1).

The representation of the numbers (hex or decimal) on output/input has nothing to do with the operations on them. The actual result are 4 32bit integers which get concatenated together - typically printed as as a single large hex string.

Comment: Hmm, I kind of understand. Perhaps show me an example of two bitwise booleans that result in 0?

Comment: 0x10 (16) and 0x0f (15) is 0:  binary 10000 & 01111 = 00000